# How to pass options in mongoose.connect()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, 
pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(node:11212) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
```

I am using Mongoose but I need to pass to options :

1. { useNewUrlParser: true }
2. { useUnifiedTopology: true }

but when I pass both it gives an error.

```
C:\Users\aA\Desktop\database pro\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:585
    throw new MongooseError('3rd parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or ' +    ^Error [MongooseError]: 3rd parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` must be a function, got "object"
    at new MongooseError (C:\Users\aA\Desktop\database pro\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\mongooseError.js:10:11)    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\aA\Desktop\database pro\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:585:11)    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\aA\Desktop\database pro\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:333:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aA\Desktop\database pro\FruitsProject\app.js:5:10)    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {  message: '3rd parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` must be a function, got "object"',  name: 'MongooseError'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add those options in the `.connect()` constructor.

Like so:

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods to pass options for `.connect`

You can do as above or also use:

```
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', false);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', false);
```

after your connect string w/o options. [See more in docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html).

Also, don't forget to close your connection to Mongo, after all operations done, by `mongoose.disconnect()`

Answer (score 0):

```
const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
};

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", options);
```